# How to update rows that were deleted from one table in the another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

1. `users` with `user_id, status` columns
2. `changes` with a `user_id, type` columns

I want to delete a row from `changes` and if `type = 5`, then set:

```
users.status = NULL Where users.user_id = changes.user_id
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Please show your approach.

Comment: Use T-SQL commands to get it done.

Comment: Your question isn't really that clear.  You want to delete a change only if it's type is 5?  Or delete all change rows, but do something special for type=5?  Also you're going to want to do that in reverse order... if you delete rows from change you won't be able to find out if they are type=5 afterwards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
-- table variable to store deleted changes
declare @deleted_changes table(user_id int, [type] int);

-- saving info from deleted changes into temp table
delete from changes 
output deleted.user_id, deleted.[type] into @deleted_changes;
-- where [some condition]

-- updating users only if corresponding changes with type = 5 were deleted
update users
set status = null
where user_id in (select user_id from @deleted_changes where [type] = 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `DELETE`, do you mean...

```
DELETE FROM Changes WHERE type = 5
```

try the following for the update....

```
UPDATE  u
SET     u.status = NULL
FROM    users u
        INNER JOIN changes c ON u.user_id = c.user_id
```